# Watermark with LstListing

Tags: listings, draftwatermark

I'm trying to add a draftwatermark to my document, but I'm having some problems with lstlisting.

Whenever I've used lstlisting (for C++ code), the background of the code section is white and overwrites (draws?) the Draft in the background.

I've seen you can change the background colour of the lstlisting, but I haven't been able to find a way to set it to transparent.

What would be the best way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Do not use option `backgroundcolor` for the listings, if you do not want the background color. `backgroundcolor={}` clears a previously set background color.
- If you are using pdfTeX in PDF mode, then package `transparent` can be used for transparency.

The following example uses page color as simplified draft watermark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\transparent{.5}\color{red}]
Hello World
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result: The red code background becomes orange:

> [image: Result]

Comment: I would aslo advise to add the line `\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` before your `\documentclass{}` as otherwise adobe reader will not display pages with transparency properly (very ragged fonts with no anti-aliasing)